# Refactoring a short case statement

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I'm having difficulty refactoring this case statement:

```
case type
when :log
  console = 'LOG'.on_blue.bold

  console_prefix = "#{prefix}:".blue.bold if prefix
when :error
  console = 'ERROR'.on_red.bold

  console_prefix = "#{prefix}:".red.bold if prefix
  console_message = message.red
when :ok
  console = 'OK'.on_green.bold

  console_prefix = "#{prefix}:".green.bold if prefix
end

puts "#{console} #{console_prefix} #{console_message}"
```

There's a variable `type` that's equal to `:log`, `:error`, or `:ok`. I'm using the [colorize](https://github.com/fazibear/colorize) gem to color my console output. All the case statement does is define what color to use with which "type". I thought about defining a class method that would set the color in the puts but that seems overly complicated.

Comment: I believe you missed to place *console_message* `method` in *:log* and *:error* branches?

Comment: @JikkuJose That was intentional, and it's a variable :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce duplication in your code like this:

```
def color_for_type(type)
  case type
  when :log
    :blue
  when :error
    :red
  when :ok
    :green
  else
    :black 
  end
end
```

And then print the message like this:

```
color           = color_for_type(type)
console         = type.to_s.upcase.send("on_#{color}").bold
console_prefix  = "#{prefix}:".send(color).bold if prefix
console_message = console_message.red if type == :error

puts "#{console} #{console_prefix} #{console_message}"
```

It's more or less the same amount of code, but there is no duplication and its intention is way more clear, both leading to increased maintainability.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, would it be better to do

`color = case type
...
end`?

Comment: I'd rather have that logic encapsulated into a method, so you can reuse it and the other method generating the final message reads easier and does only one thing (prepare the data and build the message).

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```
require 'colorize'

class CLI
  COLORS = { log: :blue, error: :red, ok: :green }

  def output
    prefix = "PREFIX"
    message = "Hello World"
    type = :error

    [
      console(type),
      console_prefix(prefix: prefix, type: type),
      console_message(message: message, type: type),
    ].compact.join(" ")
  end

  def console(type)
    type.to_s.upcase.send("on_#{COLORS[type]}").bold
  end

  def console_prefix(prefix: nil, type: :log)
    "#{prefix}:".send(COLORS[type]).bold
  end

  def console_message(message: nil, type: :error)
    message.to_s.red if type == :error
  end

  def print
    puts output
  end
end

CLI.new.print
```

**Note**:

- Removing branching may be considered a better solution.